# How to change asp.net mvc controller's date format for method's parameter..?

Tags: c#, jquery, datepicker, asp.net-core-mvc

i am taking a date field value from view page by jquery, and passed it into controller's method, date format is (dd/mm/yyyy).

it works file when the days between 1-12 and months between 1-12. 
actually it is taking mm/dd/yyyy format.

now how do i change this format to my desired format?

Comment: Change the culture on your server to one that accepts dates in the that format, or create a custom ModelBinder

Comment: could you please explain? How do i create custom modelBinder for date?

Comment: Doesn't the jQuery date picker you're using have options to specify the format of the backing value?  It's not really clear to me what the specific problem is here.

Comment: Is there a reason you want users to post dates in a format that does not match your server? To change it in the application, set the culture in you web.config.cs file

Comment: jQuery date picker provides all such functionalities, try to use jQuery date picker !

Comment: i'm taking value like var value=$('#id').val(); and passed it to a url like '/Common/ControllerName?value='+value;  yes i have datepiker for the same control.

Comment: @rohit you are correct but the .net model binder may not recognize the data in dd/mm/yyyy format, this is OPs question

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, could you please explain briefly! Would be great help.

Comment: That's why as suggested by @StephenMuecke you need to set the culture and play with the dates

Comment: @Stephen Muecke i am using .net core. Where should i put this configuration?

Comment: @SohelRana You can check with this. its a very good library https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: You should tag your question correctly (in asp.net-mvc you would add (say to Australian) `<globalization culture="en-AU" uiCulture="en-AU" />` to the `<system.web>` section, but it might be different for asp.net.core-mvc

Comment: @Rohit thanks for your reference. i already have datepiker and a inputmask to format date in client side. but when i post a date to fetch data from server then the problem occur

Comment: Thanks @Stephen Muecke

Comment: To avoid this you should use UTC format to storing the date, so whenever you pass your date in any format, just convert it to UTC and get the records. Like this http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/e954127b-42a8-4beb-bd4a-bbb24be74d0e.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When you get date on controller its again convert it into in 
.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") format after this it can be send to database ,that will work for 1-31 days.

Comment: I want the date in action method's parameter. when i debug i found nothing though date successfully passed from JQuery and ajax call to the method. i was ok when day bellow or equal to 12.

Comment: in that case you can assign date in hidden field then you can access value of hidden field in action methods then  you can convert it .Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") ;i hope it will work